# How to set limits of y axis?

Tags: d3.js

Starting from this demo http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 how could I change the y axis to go from 0 to 1000?

I tried setting a 'domain' (adding the second line)

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Did you remove `y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a muppet. The demo sets the domain further down in the code, hence why my change had no effect.

The demo sets the domain to the min-max of the y data

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));
```

I changed that to

```
y.domain([0, 1000]);
```